# Change from greyscale to color on hover within clipping mask

Tags: css, hover, mask, clipping

I understand how to change an image from grey to colour on hover through CSS and or javascript but wonder if you can do the same thing using a clipping mask.

Please see the attached image showing what I am trying to achieve. Other examples I have seen either convert the entire image or an mouse pointer area. I want a specific section or clipped area of an image to change color on hover.

[group shot showing highlighted colored area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upews.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with **SVG filters** and CSS.

> - Make the shape with a vectorial tool and convert it to [base64](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/svg)
> - Apply a filter with `<feColorMatrix>` to the image . This could be blur, grayscale, etc (more info about  [SVG filters](https://css-tricks.com/the-many-ways-to-change-an-svg-fill-on-hover-and-when-to-use-them/))
> - Set the proper sizes to apply the shaped filter over the background image.

Here is an example:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

image {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
image:hover {
  filter: url(#blurlayer2);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
          <filter id="blurlayer2" width="120%" height="100%">
            <feColorMatrix
    type="matrix"
   values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0' />
            <feGaussianBlur  stdDeviation="0" result="blur"/>
            <feImage id="feimage" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="imgmask" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
            
            <feComposite in2="imgmask" in="blur" in3="rect2" operator="in" result="comp" />
            <feMerge result="merge">
              <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
              <feMergeNode in="comp" />
            </feMerge> 
          </filter>
        </defs>
 <image  x="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://trucoslondres.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/people-1.jpg" />
  </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, the vector to Base64 certainly solves the problem of using a vector mask. 
I was hoping to start with a grayscale image and show colour on hover. I understand the grayscale filter over a colour image. I assume you would start with a colour image, applying a grayscale filter to the entire image and somehow reversing that within a vector shape on hover?